# Cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-eslint' error

Tags: eslint, create-react-app, eslintrc

I'm setting up a new project with React in Javascript environment.

I creatd a project through CRA(version 18.2.0), and I am configuring ESLint and Prettier environments.

However, when I ran `npm run start` after setting the configuration, the error occurred.

What could be the workaround?

[image]

> Failed to load plugin 'eslint' declared in '.eslintrc.js': Cannot find module 'eslint-plugin-eslint'

And this is my ESLint setup.

```js
//.eslintrc.js

module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2020: true,
  },
  extends: [
    "plugin:import/errors",
    "plugin:import/warnings",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended",
    "plugin:eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:react/recommended", // Uses the recommended rules from @eslint-plugin-react
    "prettier",
  ],
  parserOptions: {
      ecmaVersion: "latest", // Allows for the parsing of modern ECMAScript features
      sourceType: "module", // Allows for the use of imports
      ecmaFeatures: {
        jsx: true, // Allows for the parsing of JSX
      },
  },
  rules: {
    "react/prop-types": "off",
    "no-extra-semi": "error",
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": [1, { extensions: ["js", "jsx"] }],
    "arrow-parens": ["warn", "as-needed"],
    "no-unused-vars": "warn",
    "no-console": process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "warn" : "off",
    "no-debugger": process.env.NODE_ENV === "prod" ? "warn" : "off",
    "import/prefer-default-export": ["off"],
    "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": ["warn"],
    "react/jsx-props-no-spreading": [1, { custom: "ignore" }],
    "react/jsx-key": "warn",
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off",
    "import/extensions": [
      "error",
      "ignorePackages",
      {
        "js": "never",
        "jsx": "never"
      }
    ],
  },
}
```

```js
//package.json

"devDependencies": {
  "eslint": "^8.2.0",
  "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.6.0",
  "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.3",
  "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.5.1",
  "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.2.1",
  "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.28.0",
  "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.3.0"
}
```

how can i solve it?

Comment: wiht ESLint you should use plugin called `Prettier ESLint` I think. Otherwise those two might conflict too much

Comment: @O-9 Could you please elaborate a bit more??

Comment: Where did you get this `"plugin:eslint/recommended",`? It requires the plugin `eslint-plugin-eslint` to be installed, which I can't find on npm. Removing it should fix the error.

Answer (score 0):

if you did not eject your CRA, you do not need to install eslint yourself as it is in dependency of react-script. Pls check how to extend default eslint config here:

https://create-react-app.dev/docs/setting-up-your-editor/#extending-or-replacing-the-default-eslint-config